# Setting Up My wacom tablet to use only the right hand monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, wacom, ubuntu-studio

I can't seem to set up Ubuntu Studio to only use the right hand monitor with my wacom tablet.

[image: Terminal]

[image: Screenshot]

everything seems fine in display settings...
I'm using Nvdia binary driver 375.39

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools `{}` to make it look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links to were people were able to get what you were looking for. The second one is a command line fix

[Adjust​ through menu](https://forums.artrage.com/showthread.php?44397-2-Monitor-Setup-possible-to-limit-tablet-workspace-to-one-monitor-only)

[Terminal fix](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/scale-your-wacom-tablet-to-a-single-monitor/8036)

Why this happens with multiple monitors, since Wacom driver doesn't support it you need to do it through X server [a walkthrough](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Dual_and_Multi-Monitor_Set_Up#MapToOutput)

Comment: Yeah i'll try the terminal fix.

Comment: I'm still interested as to why this is happening

Comment: Anny troubleshooting here whould be apreciated.

Comment: @NicTanghe see my updated answer for what is a walk through and explains why this happens and how set it up.